# taxonomy related software to draw tree like structure

Tags: 16.04, software-recommendation

I want to know is there any taxonomy software that I can install in Ubuntu 16.04 to build tree like structure? How can I install it?

Comment: Dunno about taxonomy but genealogy software like GRAMPS builds trees. Maybe you can misuse that?

Comment: @muru Taxonomy has quite different requirements.

Comment: A friend of mine from TX is a taxonomy expert (but he uses Windows and Mac mostly). If such thing exists, even if only for other OSes, he's your man, fell free to comment and ask: https://www.youtube.com/user/AronRa

Comment: Plz give me his mail id